# Changing Vertical Space between Tkinter Widgets in a TopLevel Window

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, jupyter-notebook, tkinter-layout

I am building an Automated Data Preprocessing tool in Python where I am using Tkinter for the GUI, In the new_window, which is a TopLevel Window I want to shrink the vertical space that is unoccupied between inputs_frame and the text_widget3, and I want to place this inputs_frame right below the text_widget3. And thereafter I want to add another text_widget4 right below the inputs_frame.

Here is the code for this new window

```
    def open_new_window(self):
        new_window = tk.Toplevel()
        new_window.title("New Window")
        
        # Set the window size to full screen
        # Set the window size to full screen
        new_window.state('zoomed')

        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=20)
        text_widget.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=10, sticky="nw")

        # Redirect the output of df.info() to the text widget
        with io.StringIO() as stream:
            self.df.info(buf=stream)
            output = stream.getvalue()
            text_widget.insert(tk.END, output)
            
        # Make the text widget uneditable
        text_widget.config(state="disabled")
                
        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget2 = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=22)
        text_widget2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=5, sticky="sw")
             
        # Create another text widget to display additional info
        text_widget3 = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=80, height=3)
        text_widget3.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=1, sticky="ne")
        
        # Add a frame to the window for inputs
        inputs_frame = tk.Frame(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=text_widget3["width"])
        inputs_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, sticky="new")

        # Add labels and text inputs to the inputs frame
        label1 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 1:")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input1 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        label2 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 2:")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input2 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        # Add an "Add" button to the inputs frame
        add_button = tk.Button(inputs_frame, text="Add", width=10)
        add_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
```

Here is an output screenshot of the window after running the code -

[image]

I also have tried certain methods like changing the weights of the rows using.grid_rowconfigure() method, but even that didn't work!

And here is the full code for the whole program until now!

```
import tkinter as tk, pandas as pd, io
from tkinter import ttk, filedialog

class DataWizard:
    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.root.title("Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing")
        self.root.geometry("800x600")

        # Top layout with title
        self.title_label = tk.Label(self.root, text="Data Wizard: Automated Data Preprocessing", font=("Arial", 18))
        self.title_label.pack(pady=20)

        # Middle layout with table frame
        self.table_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.table_frame.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True, padx=20, pady=10)

        # Create a treeview widget to display table
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(self.table_frame, selectmode='browse')
        self.tree.pack(side=tk.LEFT, fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        # Add scrollbar to the treeview widget
        scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.table_frame, orient="vertical", command=self.tree.yview)
        scrollbar.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, fill=tk.Y)
        self.tree.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar.set)

        # Bottom layout with Upload CSV file label and button
        self.bottom_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.bottom_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)

        self.upload_label = tk.Label(self.bottom_frame, text="Upload CSV file", font=("Arial", 12))
        self.upload_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT, padx=10, pady=10)

        self.upload_button = tk.Button(self.bottom_frame, text="Browse", command=self.upload_csv)
        self.upload_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

        
        self.new_frame = tk.Frame(self.root, bd=0, relief=tk.GROOVE)
        self.new_frame.pack(fill=tk.X, padx=20, pady=10)
        
        # Add button to open a new window
        self.new_window_button = tk.Button(self.new_frame, text="Next", command=self.open_new_window)
        self.new_window_button.pack(side=tk.RIGHT, padx=10, pady=10)

    def upload_csv(self):
        # Open file dialog to select a CSV file
        file_path = filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes=[("CSV files", "*.csv")])

        if file_path:
            # Read CSV file as pandas dataframe
            self.df = pd.read_csv(file_path)

            # Set the columns of the treeview widget based on the dataframe columns
            self.tree["columns"] = list(self.df.columns)

            # Set column headings and widths based on the dataframe
            for col in self.df.columns:
                self.tree.heading(col, text=col.title())
                self.tree.column(col, width=len(str(self.df[col].max())), anchor = tk.CENTER)

            # Insert data into treeview widget
            for i, row in self.df.iterrows():
                self.tree.insert("", "end", values=list(row))

            # Change the upload label to the filename
            self.upload_label.config(text=file_path)

            # Add horizontal scrollbar to the treeview widget
            horizontal_scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(self.table_frame, orient="horizontal", command=self.tree.xview)
            horizontal_scrollbar.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill=tk.X)
            self.tree.configure(xscrollcommand=horizontal_scrollbar.set)

    def open_new_window(self):
        new_window = tk.Toplevel()
        new_window.title("New Window")
        
        # Set the window size to full screen
        # Set the window size to full screen
        new_window.state('zoomed')

        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=20)
        text_widget.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=15, pady=10, sticky="nw")

        # Redirect the output of df.info() to the text widget
        with io.StringIO() as stream:
            self.df.info(buf=stream)
            output = stream.getvalue()
            text_widget.insert(tk.END, output)
            
        # Make the text widget uneditable
        text_widget.config(state="disabled")
                
        # Create a text widget to display the info
        text_widget2 = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=70, height=22)
        text_widget2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=15, pady=5, sticky="sw")
             
        # Create another text widget to display additional info
        text_widget3 = tk.Text(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=80, height=3)
        text_widget3.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=1, sticky="ne")
        
        # Add a frame to the window for inputs
        inputs_frame = tk.Frame(new_window, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=text_widget3["width"])
        inputs_frame.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, sticky="new")

        # Add labels and text inputs to the inputs frame
        label1 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 1:")
        label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input1 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        label2 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 2:")
        label2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
        input2 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
        input2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")

        # Add an "Add" button to the inputs frame
        add_button = tk.Button(inputs_frame, text="Add", width=10)
        add_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
        
              
                
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = DataWizard(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you please try to make a minimal example that doesn't depend on external files? Since you're asking about the layout, it doesn't seem like we need the external csv file.

Comment: Put the left widgets in a frame and the right widgets in another frame. Then put the two frames side by side.

Comment: @BryanOakley According to the needs of the whole program, I will be needing the external csv files as well!

Comment: @ParamDhingana: we don't care about your program. We care about the question being asked, and this question does not need that data.

Comment: @acw1668 I tried doing that also, but in that case I was getting this problem with horizontal unoccupied spaces then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest solution is to put the widgets on the right into a frame, and then put the frame to the right of the other two windows.

Since it appears you don't need a grid for the two main sections on the right, I would use `pack` for them.

In the following example I create a frame named `f`. It is used as the first argument when creating `text_widget3` and `inputs_frame`. Those two are then packed inside the frame.

```
f = tk.Frame(new_window)
...
f.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=15, pady=10, rowspan=2, sticky="nsew")

text_widget3 = tk.Text(f, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=80, height=3)
inputs_frame = tk.Frame(f, bd=2, relief=tk.GROOVE, width=text_widget3["width"])

text_widget3.pack(side="top", fill="x")
inputs_frame.pack(side="top", fill="x")

# Add labels and text inputs to the inputs frame
label1 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 1:")
input1 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
label2 = tk.Label(inputs_frame, text="Label 2:")
input2 = tk.Entry(inputs_frame)
add_button = tk.Button(inputs_frame, text="Add", width=10)

label1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
input1.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
label2.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
input2.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky="w")
add_button.grid(row=2, column=0, columnspan=2, pady=10)
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Should `rowspan` be used instead of `columnspan` in `f.grid(...)`?

Comment: @acw1668: yes! Thank you for noticing that. I'll fix it.

Comment: Hey @BryanOakley How would I put a little bit of spacing in between those widgets?

Comment: @ParamDhingana: with padding, like you do with `grid` (eg: `pady=20`)